# Stale Element Reference Exception in Selenium in Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the links of different poems from https://www.poets.org/poetsorg/poems but I am getting a Stale Element Reference Exception error. I have tried increasing sleep time and WebDriverWait as well with no success. Any help will be greatly appreciated. My code is below.

```
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


def poem_scraper(url):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome("\chromedriver.exe")
    driver.get(url)
    all_links = []
    for _ in range(10):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"html.parser")
        total_poems = soup.find_all('td',attrs={'class':"views-field views-field-title"})
        for div in total_poems:
            links = div.find_all('a')
            for a in links:
                all_links.append('https://www.poets.org'+a['href'])

        timeout = 15
    #time.sleep(6)
        try:

            element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, 'next'))
            WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(element_present)
        except TimeoutException:
            print("Timed out waiting for page to load")

        test = driver.find_element_by_link_text('next')
        time.sleep(6)
        test.click()
    return(all_links)
```

StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

Comment: If your page keep refreshing, this error continue to occur,  I keep suggesting people to use WATIR whenever people come up with this error, it is handled in WATIR so nicely, WATIR automatically regain the element when element goes to stale, I am just informing you not forcing you.

Comment: Native Selenium is prone to these sorts of errors with applications where the DOM is constantly refreshed or modified, define what the front end technology is and choose a more suitable technology. A good example would be to use ProtractorJS (which is built ontop of selenium) to automate an Angular/AngularJS application

Comment: @Taran Is _Protractor_ more then a tailor made solution combining _Selenium_ and _WebDriverwait_? Whats wrong with pure _Selenium_?

Comment: @DebanjanB it is indeed, Protractor has its own built in waits that it does during any interaction. So any time you are calling .sendKeys() or .click() it waits for all $https requests to finish, therefore you don't have to do things like wait for elements to be visible or wait for spinners to disappear see documentation here http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBrowser.prototype.waitForAngular *Note that Protractor automatically applies this command before every WebDriver action.*

Comment: @DebanjanB it is specifically tailored to work for automating angular applications in that way, since it calls waitForAngular() during every element interaction by default. Having used Protractor, i've never had to care about webdriver waits